# Angular2 module level stylesheets

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am designing my website in a modular structure using [sass](/questions/tagged/sass) and I am willing to organise the stylesheets in such a way that I define a stylesheet at each module level(instead of component level) and then import it in all the components to keep a standard layout for the entire module.

So is this a good approach?

If yes, is there a method to export the CSS from the `module.ts` file to all the components. In a very similar way, the services are made available using the `providers`. This will save me the pain of importing the same CSS file in all the components individually.

Answer (score 7):

So lets say we have the following structure in our angular application

```
+-- src
|   +-- app
|   |   +-- customer
|   |   |   +-- customer.scss
|   |   |   +-- customer.module.ts
|   |   +-- product
|   |   |   +-- product.scss
|   |   |   +-- product.module.ts
|   +-- sass
|   |   +-- _common.scss
|   |   +-- app.scss
|   |   +-- project-level-styles.scss
```

We can setup our project level sass file like so:

```
@import 'common';

// project level classes
@import 'project-level-styles';

// module level classes
@import '../app/customer/customer.scss'
@import '../app/customer/product.scss'
```

So in these `customer.scss` and `product.scss` I will have classes that are common throughout the many components inside that module.

It should be noted that when you create a stylesheet not at the component level and put it somewhere else like inside a module or project directory, the way angular treats those styles is different.

[Angular Component Styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

> Angular can bundle component styles with components, enabling a more modular design than regular stylesheets. The selectors you put into a component's styles apply only within the template of that component.

So please be aware that any stylesheets not associated with the components `styleUrls` array it can be applied to any element in your site (if you don't use specificity). It's not applied only to that module, so this may not be a solution for all situations, but it's something that I do for my modules, understanding this I can write my styles in that modular stylesheet to be specific to that module by targeting the root element for that module...

**component vs global**

In my application my `customerModule` has a root component called `customerComponent` and I have a root element in that html that has a class of:

`customer-container`

So inside my `customer.scss` I can prepend all of my styles like this:

```
.customer-container .info-heading {
  font-size: 15px; color: #333;
}

.customer-container .section-divider {
  margin-top: 1em; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

So I can now achieve some level of specificity that keep my styles from bleeding into other project components.

Answer (score 1):

> So is this a good approach?

Its subjective. Angular modules help organise an application into cohesive blocks of functionality. Would I want different styles for different blocks functionalities? Highly unlikely.

> Is there a method to export the CSS from the module.ts file to all the components.

No. Its only supported at component level. The workaround would be to have single css file referred by all the module components. Then again a good practice would be to modularise the css and use them at component levels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Definitely approach is good to have different style sheets for each component. Even Angular CLI is following the same approach. 
You can have a look and get hands on: [LINK](https://cli.angular.io/)

> So is this a good approach?

Yes this a perfect approach when it comes to arranging file structure for Angular app.

> If yes, is there a method to export the CSS from the module.ts file to
>   all the components.

By default Angular CLI doesn't give any stylesheet for module and it make sense as well. Why you need stylesheet at module level?
You can add styles related to component in component level stylesheet and additionally if you want you can have one stylesheet at project level where you can add all common styles for project.

Comment: What if I want module level stylesheet instead of having one at the product level. Since each module has separate set of functionalities I am willing to have same set of design features of that entire module instead of a component or a project.

Comment: Well if you are so sure about having it at module level and you have requirement like that. You can always add it. Angular doesn't restrict to add one at component level.