# Is there a way to setup module level css in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want each module of my angular application to have separate css file and I not want that to be project level css but instead module level, I know angular provide by default component level css by that I not want to use and not importing single css file in each component as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 module level stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180336/angular2-module-level-stylesheets)

Comment: No it only giving solution to use css at component level

Comment: but I want css at the module level

Comment: it does give approach of module level css. by defining a css inside module folder and importing it in components where you need it.

Comment: so I have to import everytime, can I avoid this

Comment: otherwise it will 100 imports if there are 100 components in that module

Comment: and it will also make components heavier in size etc

Comment: imports will make component heavy? in which world you are coding?

Comment: I am thinking that if 100 times I added import to each component then will be heavy i.e css will repeat 100 times in js file of that module

Comment: in that way the file mbs will increase I mean